# Does HP 8530w support Wifi 802.11n?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, 802.11n

According to vendor site HP 8530w supports 802.11n draft mode. My Windows 7 tell me that network card is 5100 ABG and know nothing about N mode ([guys from Intel forum](http://communities.intel.com/message/71193) mentioned, that 802.11N versions must ended with N letter, e.g. 5100 ABN). Not sure if it matter, but my laptop model id is #FU462EA.

How could I check that my Wifi card compliant with 802.11n (I suspect that "draft N"  could have two "special" meaning: doesn't work with 802.11n at all or requires special activation of the mode).

Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it often happens answer is "It depends". It the case it depends from a country where your laptop was purchased. 802.11n wifi adapter includes in all HP 8530w models except 3 countries: Ukraine, Russia and Pakistan.

Any ideas why HP team made so strange country based choice?

Answer (score 2):

According to [HP's site](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/za/en/sm/WF06b/321957-321957-64295-3955549-3955549-3781677-3817608.html) your notebook supports 802.11n. Does your router support 802.11n ? 
Additionally, the site you linked to mentions:

- Draft-N speeds are only obtained with WPA2-AES security.
- enable QoS on your router configuration

Are both conditions met ?

Comment: Yes on both questions (DLink DIR-685; WPA/WPA2, AES, PSK). I hope that 802.11n will works w/o any authentication at all, but I failed (54 Mbit, router shows g mode). I suspect that issue is in wifi card (it doesn't support N mode or a driver for Windows 7 don't know my card). Ahead of your question I upgrade my wifi driver for latest version and try both from HP and from Intel site.

Comment: Maybe a firmware upgrade to the router as well.

Comment: Latest version :(

Comment: @FoxyBOA - what mode is the router set at, Mixedmode G+N or just N ?

Answer (score 0):

Any ideas why HP team made so strange country based choice?

Those countries regulatory do not allow 802.11n - but are just starting to do so, later this year 802.11n devices will appear there.

Comment: No idea. It was a mystery for me.